# boost::asio non-blocking read byte by byte

Tags: c++, boost

I have got a TCP stream, and need to read a packages from it of the following format (simplified):

```
[ header = X bytes bytes ]
  [ crc        = 2 bytes ]
  [ data_len   = 2 bytes ]
  [ header_len = 2 bytes ]
  [ some text  = X bytes ]
[ data  = data len bytes]
```

The requirement is to use boost::asio library. As it is probably already clear, I need to read it in the following order:
1. read first 6 bytes to determine data_len and header_len;
2. read header_len bytes to header buffer;
3. read data_len bytes to data buffer;

The question is how to read n bytes to boost::asio::buffer, read few more and append it in non-blocking way. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the async [tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html)? [The examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html)? [The reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html)? If you read those then you should have all information you need to at the very least try something yourself.

Comment: @Joachim, I did. I swear. I couldn't find any good example, which solves the described problem: parsing packet from TCP stream byte by byte. Tack.

Comment: I would read a fixed buffer and feed a custom object to parse it, returning at the same time the amount of bytes processed in that call just to get used in the next one.

Comment: [`async_read`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read.html) seems like a good place to start. And you always knows exactly how many bytes to read, which mean you can easily create the appropriately sized buffer, no need to read "byte by byte".

Comment: You can just use async_read_until and write a function to tell whether you have a complete message.